# Conditional field for a content type

Tags: forms

I am looking for a way to hide/show some fields depending on what users select on another field. Users can select between *four wheeler* or *two wheeler*. If users select *four wheeler* from a drop-down, they see different set of fields than the ones show when *two wheeler* is selected. As there are many common fields I am looking to use the same content type for both cases.

What I have tried so far is using `hook_form_alter()` or  `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` in the .theme file. Neither of them seems to work for me.

This is the code I tried. (Please do note I am using *themename* instead of the machine name of the theme; also the field names has been changed.)

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface; // at top of themename.theme


function themename_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_album_type_name']['#states'] = [
    'visible' => [
      'select[name="field_album_type"]' => ['value' => 'custom']
    ]
  ];
}
```

Comment: So far, you stated facts, without asking any explicit question. Since you are talking of code you wrote, you should show the code you wrote so far. Did you try the #states property for form fields?

Comment: @kiamlaluno thank you for your response. I have added the code , could you take a look ?

Comment: Themename should be admin theme name or code to be added to module

Comment: Keep in mind that theme hooks are invoked just when the theme is used for the currently rendered page. It's not that the hooks are invoked for all the enabled themes, contrary to modules.